# Expansion (asymptotic) of scalar function of a square matrix , in terms of determinant of argument?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, linear-algebra

The title says it all. I have a scalar function (really, a determinant) of a square matrix argument. Can I find an (asymptotic) expansion of the function, in a series in the determinant of the argument? Any ideas, references)

Ok, as asked,. giving more context. A simplified version of my problem is
the determinant
$ \det( (I-\psi)^2 - \rho^2 \psi^2 ) $

where $I$ is the identity matrix, $\psi$ is a matrix and $\rho$ is a number less than one in absolute value.  Wanted is an expansion in the determinant of $(I-\psi)$.

Thanks for the references!

Comment: Clearly not, for the function $f(A)=A_{11}$ for example.  You'll need to give a lot more details to get to a situation where the answer is not obviously negative.

Comment: This may only be peripherally related.  If you consider only functions of matrices, such that the function is rotationally invariant (i.e. if  $f \colon Sym_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f \circ U = f$ for all $U \in O(n)$, then $f$ can be shown to be a function of only the invariants $\sigma_k$ of its argument (where $\sigma_1$ is the trace, $\sigma_n$ is the determinant, and all the ones in between can in a way be considered to measure "mean change in $k$-volume".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooney–Rivlin_solid for a concrete example.

Comment: Here's another useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors (see "Engineering Application").

Comment: Is your scalar function _just_ the determinant? Wouldn't the expansion just be the determinant itself? I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: What does asymptotic mean, in this context? $\det \psi$ is small? large? neither?

Comment: -- What does asymptotic mean? For instance, since I now the answer when $\rho=0$, an expansion in \rho could be usefull.